# Calling Oracle Stored Procedure from C#

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I'm trying to call an oracle stored procedure 'spValidateDBA' from C# but i'm always getting an error - "PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SPVALIDATEDBA'" while trying to do so.

The issue is probably occuring while trying to call the stored procedure parameter 'UserRole' from C#,it's type isn't set properly in the C# code and i have no idea how to set it correctly.Can someone please help me out here,i really need to get this resolved soon.

**C# code:-**

```
            string a = txtUsrId.Text.ToUpper();
            string sConnectionString = "Data Source=XE;User ID=sys;Password=system;DBA 
            PRIVILEGE=sysdba";
            OracleConnection myConnection = new OracleConnection(sConnectionString);
            OracleCommand myCommand = new OracleCommand("spValidateDBA", myConnection);
            myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            myCommand.CommandText = "spValidateDBA";
            myCommand.Parameters.Add("UserId", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 50);
            myCommand.Parameters["UserId"].Value = a;
            myCommand.Parameters.Add("UserRole",OracleDbType.Varchar2, 50).Direction =
            ParameterDirection.Output;
            myCommand.Parameters.Add("UserIdOut", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 50).Direction = 
            ParameterDirection.Output;
            var rolechk = false;
            string checkrole = "DBA";
            myConnection.Open();
            myCommand.ExecuteReader();
//this is where i'm getting the error "PLS-00306: wrong number 
//or types of arguments in call to 'SPVALIDATEDBA'"
```

**Stored procedure spValidateDBA**

```
create or replace PROCEDURE spValidateDBA(
    UserId IN VARCHAR2,
UserRole OUT STRING_ARRAY,
 UserIdOut OUT VARCHAR2)
  AS
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select GRANTED_ROLE bulk collect into UserRole from DBA_USERS DU,DBA_ROLE_PRIVS DRP where DU.USERNAME=UserId AND DU.USERNAME=DRP.GRANTEE';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select USERNAME into UserIdOut from DBA_USERS DU where DU.USERNAME=UserId';
  END spValidateDBA;
```

STRING_ARRAY is of string array type as declared in this statement:

```
CREATE TYPE STRING_ARRAY AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50);
```

Please let me know for any questions.

Comment: Maybe look at this - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/164705/Oracle-PL-SQL-collections

Answer (score 0):

Command text must be like this:

```
myCommand.CommandText = "spValidateDBA(:UserId, :UserRole, :UserIdOut )";
```

Then you must call `myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();` instead of ExecuteReader.

`myCommand.Parameters.Add("UserRole",OracleDbType.Varchar2, 50)` is also wrong when you return a TABLE instead of VARCHAR. I think it should be similar to this one:

```
myCommand.Parameters.Add("UserRole");
myCommand.Parameters["UserRole"].CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
myCommand.Parameters["UserRole"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

I never used `PLSQLAssociativeArray` as output parameter, so I am not sure about the details. Maybe your procedure could return a SYS_REFCURSOR instead.

In your PL/SQL procedure I don't see any need for dynamic SQL, make it simple:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE spValidateDBA(
   UserId IN VARCHAR2, UserRole OUT STRING_ARRAY, UserIdOut OUT VARCHAR2)
  AS
 BEGIN
    select GRANTED_ROLE bulk collect into UserRole from DBA_USERS DU,DBA_ROLE_PRIVS DRP where DU.USERNAME=UserId AND DU.USERNAME=DRP.GRANTEE;
    select USERNAME into UserIdOut from DBA_USERS DU where DU.USERNAME= UserId';
 END spValidateDBA;
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion my friend,let me check once.